# Typescript extract a dynamic oneOf type

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
type Foo =
    | { $case: 'a'; a: { id: string } }
    | { $case: 'b'; b: { message: string } }
    | { $case: 'c'; c: { message: string } }
    | { $case: 'd'; d: { id: string } }
;

type Cases = Foo['$case']
```

The `$case` is also the name of the `key`. I want to extract only the cases that extend `{ id: string }`, for example. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
type withId = {
    [K in Cases]: Foo[K] extends { id: string } ? Foo[K] : never
}
```

How can I do this and also create a type guard for this?

```
if(hasId(currentCase)) {
  return currentCase.id;
}
```

Comment: Your example is inconsistent and needs more context. What is `cases` and `case`? Is `case` a typo and it's supposed to be `cases`? `case` is a reserved word, so it can't be a variable name. If `cases` is supposedly of type `Foo`, then how come you can use `cases.id` (if it is a typo)? You would still have to narrow between the "a" and "d" cases. You could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbQyPN), but since your example has so many problems, I don't know for sure if this is solves the problem.

Comment: @caTS this is exactly what I needed. Do you want to create an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved using distributive conditional types not mapped types and it can be achieved like this:

```
type SelectFromType<K, F extends keyof K, G> =
    K extends any ?
    K[F] extends keyof K ?
    K[K[F]] extends G ?
    K : never : never : never;
```

Then it can be used like (for example):

```
type R = SelectFromType<Foo, '$case', { id: string }>
```

and now `type R` is:

```
{
    $case: 'a';
    a: {
        id: string;
    };
} | {
    $case: 'd';
    d: {
        id: string;
    };
}
```

As for your second question, I think you mean a custom type guard to make sure wheter a `Foo` typed object can be narrowed to `SelectFromType<Foo, '$case', { id: string }>` or not.

```
function hasId(foo: Foo): foo is SelectFromType<Foo, '$case', { id: string }> {
    if (typeof foo[foo.$case].id === "string")
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

For example:

```
function myFunc(foo: Foo) {
    if (hasId(foo)) {
        //here foo type is :
        //{ $case: "a"; a: { id: string; } } | { $case: "d"; d: { id: string } }
    }
    else {
        //and here is :
        //{ $case: "b"; b: { message: string; } } | { $case: "c"; c: { message: string } }
    }
}
```

Comment: if(hasId(foo)) {}

Comment: @undefined I modified the type guard which I mentioned. I hope it helps.